# How can I output datetime and offset

Tags: android, flutter, datetime, dart

I am making a Date Time App on Flutter that I saw on YouTube. Whenever I try to run the program, it always says "E/flutter (31302): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception:" on the console with a bunch of other packages. I don't know what to do and what solution I can do. BTW I disabled some plugin on my flutter to speed up my Android Studio. Do you think it is one of the reasons for my error? I want to show the datetime and offset to the console first like in the video. I tried opening my net in hopes of maybe not connecting to the internet might help but I still got the same error. Thank you and God Bless. Here my code.

```
'''
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class loading extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _loadingState createState() => _loadingState();
}

class _loadingState extends State<loading> {
  void getTime() async{
    Response response = await get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London');
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    //print(data);

    String datetime = data['datetime'];
    String offset = data['utc_offset'];
    print (datetime);
    print(offset);
        
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getTime();

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('Loading'),
    );
  }
}
```

'''

here is the error message:

'''

```
Launching lib\main.dart on CPH1803 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Waiting for CPH1803 to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63067/xeetvh83VWI=/ws
Syncing files to device CPH1803...
D/libc-netbsd(12939): [getaddrinfo]:  hostname=worldtimeapi.org;  servname=(null);  app_pid=12939;  app_uid=10145;  ai_flags=1024;  ai_family=0; ai_socktype=1 from prox result 0
E/flutter (12939): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: 
E/flutter (12939): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:62:7)
E/flutter (12939): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12939): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:91:38)
E/flutter (12939): #2      BaseClient.get (package:http/src/base_client.dart:27:7)
E/flutter (12939): #3      get.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:46:36)
E/flutter (12939): #4      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:20)
E/flutter (12939): #5      get (package:http/http.dart:46:5)
E/flutter (12939): #6      _loadingState.getTime (package:world_time/pages/loading.dart:12:31)
E/flutter (12939): #7      _loadingState.initState (package:world_time/pages/loading.dart:27:5)
E/flutter (12939): #8      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:58)
E/flutter (12939): #9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
E/flutter (12939): #10     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter (12939): #11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter (12939): #12     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
E/flutter (12939): #13     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter (12939): #14     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter (12939): #15     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
E/flutter (12939): #16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
E/flutter (12939): #17     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5)
E/flutter (12939): #18     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
E/flutter (12939): #19     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter (12939): #20     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter (12939): #21     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
E/flutter (12939): #22     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter (12939): #23     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter (12939): #24     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
E/flutter (12939): #25     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter (12939): #26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter (12939): #27     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
E/flutter (12939): #28     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
E/flutter (12939): #29     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
E/flutter (12939): #30     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5)
E/flutter (12939): #31     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4791:11)
E/flutter (12939): #32     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
E/flutter (12939): #33     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter (12939): #34     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter (12939): #35     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
E/flutter (12939): #36     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter (12939): #37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter (12939): #38     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
E/flutter (12939): #39     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter (12939): #40     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter (12939): #41     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
E/flutter (12939): #42     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
E/flutter (12939): #43     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
E/flutter (12939): #44     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5)
E/flutter (12939): #45     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4791:11)
E/flutter (12939): #46     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
E/flutter (12939): #47     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter (12939): #48     Ele
```

'''
If my question is still confusing please let me know so that I can give the problem. Please help me Thank you.

Comment: I disable the following plugins: Android Games, ChangeReminders, Compose, Copyright, Coverage, EditorConfig, Firebase App Indexing, Firebase Testing, Google Developer Samples, Java bytecode compiler, LayoutLib Standard, Mercurial, Subversion, Task    Management, Terminal, TestNG,  TextMate bundles